# how to write clean url i have two url from different folder first url from root directory and other one from root/tutorials/htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have following two url i would like to make it clean url

original url

`https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/get_data.php?qid=ADO`

i would like to clean url like this

`https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/ADO`

second url is `https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/tutorials.php?qid=459`

i would like to clean url like this `https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/459`

i have tried these rules

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ tutorials.php?qid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w.-]+)/?$ get_data.php?qid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

with the help of above rules i'm able to achieve clean url like this

`https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/ADO` 
 and
`https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/459`

Comment: Is `tutorial/` a real directory? Does it already have a .htaccess?

Comment: yes, tutorials/ is a real directory /home/evidhya/public_html/tutorials/.htaccess

Comment: i have 2 .htaccess file second in the evidhya directory /home/evidhya/public_html/.htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a .htaccess inside `/tutorials/` directory with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ tutorials.php?qid=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ get_data.php?qid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure there is no other rules in `tutorials/.htaccess`.

Now load these 2 URLs in browsers to test this:

- `https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/ADO`
- `https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/459`

Comment: i have created .htaccess inside /tutorials/ directory with these rule but i doesn't reflect anything

Comment: both url is working 1.https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/get_data.php?qid=ADO
2.https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/ADO how can i stop first one

Comment: i want to redirect old url to new url

Comment: Once these rules are there, you should only use pretty links on your pages. Are old links indexed in search engines?

Comment: sir with these rules it is  working fine now i want to achieve like this https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/ADO/Introduction how can i achieve this

Comment: sir  id 459 should be hidden https://www.evidhya.com/tutorials/459 instead of  evidhya.com/tutorials/ADO/Introduction subject title name and topic name should be in the url like subject name ADO and topic name introduction

Comment: @JaiPrakash: Let's not add new requirements in comments. If this answer worked for the problem stated in question then you should accept this answer and post a new question for additional requirement.

Comment: yes sir, i will post new question

Comment: i did that sir i have upvoted also.